# Can I create Excel Graph with width proportional to the date period?

Tags: excel, graph, pivot-table

For example, suppose A, B and C points:

---

Table:

A                           01/01/2001                1

B                           01/01/2002                1

C                           01/01/2010                1

---

The spacing between A and B must be less than B and C, and this space is proportional to the distance between the dates.

This is expected graph:

---

Graphic:

1                1                                                                          1

O ---------- O --------------------------------------------------------- O

2001         2002                                                                    2010

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an Excel line chart, Excel will probably recognize the X values as dates and plot the points as you want it to. If it doesn't, you can format the axis and make sure it is a date type axis.

Just select the dates and the values before making the chart. If there is actually a column with A, B, C in it, don't include it in the selection before making the chart.

Comment: This works for static tables, but how do I do this in a pivot table?

Comment: Pivot charts force you to use all of the pivot table data in them. You can make a regular chart from part of a pivot table, as I describe in my tutorial: http://peltiertech.com/regular-charts-from-pivot-tables/

Comment: Thanks, I'd see your post.